# How to transfer nested object to server using POST method in jquery using paypal.request.post() function

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, post, paypal

```js
var a = [{
  "username": "r",
  "password": "r"
}];

var b = [
{"id":"90425","value":"xzc"},
{"id":"63905","value":"zxcz"},
{"id":"23094","value":["Japan"]},
{"id":"65342","value":"male"},
{"id":"21743","value":"Student"}
];

var result = Object.assign( {}, a[0],{ pp: b  } );

$("#r").text(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="r">
```

can i send this result variable using post method using jquery?

i'm implementing paypal following   https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server example.

here this `paypal.request.post('/demo/checkout/api/paypal/payment/execute/',result)`

line not work in nested object "result".

if i do  network debug in chrome browser then FORM DATA shown like this

`username:r
password:r
pp:[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

how can i transfer nested object using paypal.request.post() function?